# Can we use Codable instead of JSonSerialization to serialize? what are the advantage and disadvantages of codable compared to jsonserializer

Tags: nsjsonserialization, codable

Can we use Codable instead of JSonSerialization to serialize?
what are the advantage and disadvantages of codable compared to jsonserialization

Comment: `Codable` is based on `JSONSerialization`. But rather than getting dictionaries and arrays you can convert the JSON directly to structs or classes.

Comment: So, if we want to get values from dictionary and array, we should use jsonSerialization instaed of codable.

Comment: Yes, but structs and classes are preferable.